# How can I get all the facebook page by category or subscribe on adding them?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

For example: https://graph.facebook.com/181017065298015

Page has category, but I can't get category by FQL query like

```
SELECT categories FROM page WHERE name= "..."
```

This query return empty set

In the graph API  I can subscribe for update only one page... But I need subscribe on adding any page with certain category! I don't found this in API.

There is a way to get this information by using API?

In other case direct me pls on operational metod

UPD:
Search page by graph API not allowed by page category, it works only for "name" field
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Games&type=page&access_token=...

Answer (score 0):

There's a missmatch between the Graph API and FQL concerning the Page information available. The Graph API uses `category`, which is the "old" field, and FQL uses the newer `categories`. I think there's no way around this, one could consider this as a "flaw" in Facebooks API design.

Concerning your other question on "subscribing" (you mean liking I guess) all pages of certain category: This is NOT possible.

Comment: Well, you weren't asking about search. Basically, I think it's not possible what you want to do.

Comment: And, you should remove your app access token!

Comment: Thanks!
It seems that using the Graph API I can not filter the results by category. Search works only for field "name".

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Games&type=page&access_token=

FQL doesn't work for me: "select categories ..." return me empty array.

It seems that the parsing is the only option left.